# Can't combine command line argument with string?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write to a file, in a specified area from the console line. (Like C:)
The application crashes when I publish and run its .exe
My code is:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string arg1 = null;
            if (args.Length > 0)
                arg1 = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine(arg1);
            Console.WriteLine(args);
            string tf = "\tf1.txt";
            string tf1 = arg1 + tf;
            Console.WriteLine(tf1);


System.Console.Title = "Data Adder (For the test)";
Random rnd = new Random();
int r1 = rnd.Next(0, 20);
byte[] bytes = new byte[255*r1];

var TF1 = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@arg1+"tf1.txt",FileMode.Open));
TF1.Write(bytes);
TF1.Close();
Console.ReadKey();


        }

        private static int Random(int p1, int p2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

anyone know whats wrong? (Its in C#)

Comment: Did you run it in a debugger? What exception is thrown?

Comment: What is  `arg1` when you output it? If the program crashes, what error message does it display? How about single-stepping the program in the IDE and telling us which line crashes?

Comment: So have you checked what the value of `@arg1+"tf1.txt"` actually is? Have you verified said value is actually pointing to a valid file?

Comment: that is the link+tf1.txt, I added a "\" and now the t is missing so file is still not found

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when generating file paths. Use Path.Combine instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Path.combine generated C:tf1.txt, I can't use "\" because its an illegal character.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing just `C:` from command line, you need to switch this line

```
var TF1 = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@arg1+"tf1.txt",FileMode.Open));
```

to

```
var TF1 = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(arg1+@"\tf1.txt",FileMode.Open));
```

Or the path is invalid `C:tf1.txt`

Also, you should check if the file exists before opening it:

```
if (File.Exists(arg1 + @"\tf1.txt"))
{
    var TF1 = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(arg1 + @"\tf1.txt", FileMode.Open));
    TF1.Write(bytes);
    TF1.Close();
}
```

---

Your full code is (with minimal changes):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string arg1 = null;
            if (args.Length > 0)
                arg1 = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine(arg1);
            Console.WriteLine(args);
            string tf = "\tf1.txt";
            string tf1 = arg1 + tf;
            Console.WriteLine(tf1);


            System.Console.Title = "Data Adder (For the test)";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int r1 = rnd.Next(0, 20);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[255 * r1];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                bytes[i] = 65;

            string filepath = Path.Combine(arg1, @"\tf1.txt");
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                var TF1 = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open));
                TF1.Write(bytes);
                TF1.Close();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();


        }

        private static int Random(int p1, int p2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "\" is a illigal character.

Comment: Did you put `@` before a string with it?

Comment: Hmm, do you get an error? The code compiles and runs fine for me.

Comment: I posted the full code that works for me if you pass `c:` as command line.

Comment: Its not writing bytes to the file.

Comment: I did write 0 as the array was not initialised. I modified the code above to initialise the array to 'A' character. But let's finish that question at that stage as your original problem is solved. If you have more questions, please ask them separately. Stack Overflow works this way: one problem in one question.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're using a backslash here....

```
string tf = "\tf1.txt";
```

but not here...

```
var TF1 = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@arg1+"tf1.txt",FileMode.Open));
```

It's worth you stepping through the code and seeing what the values are.

Comment: that was a test. still flawed.

Comment: "\" is also a illegal character.